# Math equation with numbering

Tags: equations

I am trying to number my equation. I am using the following code

```
\begin{equation} \label{equ1}
a_1^2 + a_2^2 = a_3^2 
\end{equation}
```

But the result is (0.1). But I want (1) like this. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! We need to have a minimal, yet complete, code to determine what happens. A snippet is not enough for that.

Comment: Hi, I am using documentclass scrbook. This is the reason the equation number is coming like that. but I need to use scrbook and my equation has to be like (1) (2) ... so on. here is my latex https://www.overleaf.com/read/nxdnycwxstxb

Comment: I suppose the first digit is the number of the current section? If that is indeed the case, you can add to your preamble `counterwithout{equation}{section}`.

Comment: yes. But i need remove that number.

Comment: Are you gonna use the chapter level heading or not? if not why you didn't use `scrartcl` class

Comment: I need to give chapter names. so can not use article or scrartcl class. :(

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}`

Comment: I've just tested it: `\counterwithout{equation}{section}` works fine.

Comment: You guys are life saviors. A big thank you guys... :)